# Prove that for all $n \in \Bbb N$ that $f_n$ has exactly $n$ zero points, all in the interval $(-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, roots

We define the function $f_n: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. The function $f_0=1$. For all $n \in \Bbb N$ ,

$f_{n+1}(x)  = \frac{d}{dx}((x^2-1)f_n(x))$

Prove that for all $n \in \Bbb N$ that $f_n$ has exactly $n$ zero points, all in the interval $(-1,1)$.

So the question before this was to prove that $f_n$ was a polynomial function of degree $n$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$. I also calculated $f_1$, because I wanted to prove this using induction.

So far, I only have that $f_1=2x$, so it has 1 zero point, which lies in $(-1,1)$. So the statement holds for $n=1$.

Let $f_k$ have k zero points all in $(-1,1)$. Prove $f_{k+1}$ has $k+1$ zero points in $(-1,1)$. So I know that $f_{k+1}$ is a polynomial function of degree $k+1$. So it can have $0, 1 ,2 ... k+1$ zero points.

I'm stuck here. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f_n$ has $n$ zeros in $(-1,1)$, $(x^2-1)f_n(x)$ has $n+2$ zeros in $[-1,1]$, two of which are $\pm1$. So, by Rolle's theorem, $f_{n+1}$ has one zero between any two zeros of $(x^2-1)f_n(x)$ and therefore it has $n+1$ zeros, at least. But since it is a polynomial whose degree is $n+1$, it cannot have more than $n+1$ zeros.

Answer (score 0):

You know $(x^2-1)f_k(x)$ has $k+2$ zeros in the closed interval $[-1,1]$.
What does that imply for its derivative?